why two | to define union type
err is union type.
err: NodeJS.ErrnoException | null

Why does options need two | to define union type?
function readFile(
path: PathOrFileDescriptor,
options:
    | ({
        encoding: BufferEncoding;
        flag?: string | undefined;
    } & Abortable)
    | BufferEncoding,
callback: (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException | null, data: string) => void,): void


It's not needed, it's just syntactic sugar to easily add and remove components of the union, pretty much the same way you can add a comma after the last element of an array: [a, b, c,].

Unions may optionally start with a | character.
These are exactly the same type:
type A = 1 | 2
type B = | 1 | 2

The reason for this is to make multiline unions easier to read by having consistent formatting on every single line.
For example this:
type A =
  1
  | 2
  | 3
  | 4

Can instead be this:
type A =
  | 1
  | 2
  | 3
  | 4

And again, these are exactly equivalent. It's just a syntax feature with no additional meaning.
